# PHP Copy image and load in HTML

Tags: php, image, path

I have uploaded an image to the folder:

```
/var/www/uploads/img.png
```

using the relative path

```
../uploads/img.png
```

I then load the image with the following code:

```
$img = copy('../uploads/9', '/tmp/profile_picture');
```

Which returns true

And my googling got me to this:

```
<img src="/tmp/profile_picture" alt="profile_picture" />
```

I have tried the above with and without .png ending. still not working.

I just need to get out 1 picture and display in an image tag, and i always know the exact path and filename of my image.

**EDIT**

After the first answer in this thread i have tried the following:

```
$image = '../uploads/9';

$info = getimagesize($image);

// output the image
header("Content-Disposition: filename={$image};");
header("Content-Type: {$info["mime"]}");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');

readfile($image);
```

And i call the script here:

```
<img src="profile_picture.php" alt="profile_picture" />
```

and i get 404.

I've tried various paths for the $image

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not working means what

Comment: `<img src="uploads/img.png"/>` why do you need to copy it?

Comment: Why don't you use `<img src="/uploads/img.png" alt="profile_picture" />`? If you start with `/` on a website, it means the web server root, not your local file system root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1: correct your use of copy()

Use:
`$img = copy('/tmp/profile_picture', '../uploads/9');`
 instead.

From the [PHP.net docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php), the format for the copy function is:

`copy ( string $source , string $dest [, resource $context ] )`

Where the parameters:
`source` » Path to the source file.

`dest` » The destination path. If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.

`context` » A valid context resource created with stream_context_create().

## Step 2 (1): upload image to a web accessible path

You'll need to know your web root. 
Consider this folder structure:

`/var/www` » your www root

`/var/www/project1` » your www root

`/var/www/project1/assets/img` » your publicly accessible images directory for your project

then upload your image to the above path: `/var/www/project1/assets/img/img.png`

and use the image like this (from `index.html`):

`<img src="/assets/img/img.png" alt="Image">`

## Step 2 (2): OR wrap your image in a php file

This requires a custom php file, and it's use in a image tag.

Example:
`image.php`

```
<?php
$image = '/var/www/uploads/img.png';

$info = getimagesize($image);

// output the image
header("Content-Disposition: filename={$image};");
header("Content-Type: {$info["mime"]}");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');

readfile($image);
?>
```

`index.html`

```
<img src="image.php" alt="Image">
```

**Explanation**

This option just wraps your image in php script and the script is called instead.

I use this if the image cannot be publicly accessible and/or I have to do some checks to see if the current user is worthy of accessing the image.

::Used by most file sharing web-apps

Comment: I have copied your script and it returns 404, i have tried with the php script residing in the same folter as the view

Comment: And the first part of your answer is obsolete and i think you misunderstood. Source is uploads/9 and destination is /temp/9

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

Use the function sys_get_temp_dir() to upload the images directly to the temporary folder.

Then

```
$path = '/tmp/profile_picture';
$imageData = file_get_contents($path);
// display in view
echo sprintf('<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s" />', base64_encode($imageData));
```